# MVC4 dynamically adding unkown number of editors without repeating a lot of code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm using C#, MVC4 and jQuery.
The requirements given to me are that I need to be able to add records to a database which translates into editable fields in a view.

The view has tabs, groups, lines and items which need to be populated depending on what is in the database.
I have been able to achieve what I want using a viewmodel containing a list of "Tabs"; each Tab contains a list of "Groups"; each Group contains a list of "Lines" and each Line contains a list of "Items".

What ends up happening for me is that I need to repeat a lot of code that is exactly the same for the editors. This is what I want to avoid.

So in my view I've got something like:

```
    @for (int tabIndex = 0; Model.Tabs != null && tabIndex < Model.Tabs.Count; tabIndex++)
    {
        <div id="tab-@Model.Tabs[tabIndex].TabID" class="tab-content">
        @for (int groupIndex = 0; Model.Tabs[tabIndex].Groups != null && groupIndex < Model.Tabs[tabIndex].Groups.Count; groupIndex++)
        {
            <legend>@Model.Tabs[tabIndex].Groups[groupIndex].Name</legend>
            //This is the part that is not working but I would like to
            AddEditorsForGroup(tabIndex, groupIndex);
...
...
```

And then I also have this in the view:

```
@{
    public void AddEditorsForGroup(int TabIndex, int GroupIndex)
    {
        for (int lineIndex = 0; Model.Tabs[TabIndex].Groups[GroupIndex].Lines != null && lineIndex < Model.Tabs[TabIndex].Groups[GroupIndex].Lines.Count; lineIndex++)
        {
            for (int itemIndex = 0; Model.Tabs[TabIndex].Groups[GroupIndex].Lines[lineIndex].Items != null && itemIndex < Model.Tabs[TabIndex].Groups[GroupIndex].Lines[lineIndex].Items.Count; itemIndex++)
            {
                AddLabelAndEditor(TabIndex, GroupIndex, lineIndex, itemIndex);
            }
        }
    }
    public void AddLabelAndEditor(int TabIndex, int GroupIndex, int LineIndex, int ItemIndex)
    {
            <div class="_20">
                    <p>
        switch (Model.Tabs[TabIndex].Groups[GroupIndex].Lines[LineIndex].Items[ItemIndex].DisplayTypeEdit.ToLower().Replace(" ", string.Empty))
        {
            case "checkbox":
                Html.LabelFor(vm => vm.Tabs[TabIndex].Groups[GroupIndex].Lines[LineIndex].Items[ItemIndex].ValueBoolean, Model.Tabs[TabIndex].Groups[GroupIndex].Lines[LineIndex].Items[ItemIndex].Name);
                Html.CheckBoxFor(vm => vm.Tabs[TabIndex].Groups[GroupIndex].Lines[LineIndex].Items[ItemIndex].ValueBoolean);
                break;
            case "dropdownlist":
                Html.LabelFor(vm => vm.Tabs[TabIndex].Groups[GroupIndex].Lines[LineIndex].Items[ItemIndex].ValueString, Model.Tabs[TabIndex].Groups[GroupIndex].Lines[LineIndex].Items[ItemIndex].Name);
                Html.DropDownListFor(vm => vm.Tabs[TabIndex].Groups[GroupIndex].Lines[LineIndex].Items[ItemIndex].ValueString, Model.Tabs[TabIndex].Groups[GroupIndex].Lines[LineIndex].Items[ItemIndex].ValueSelectList);
                break;
            case "multiselectlist":
                Html.LabelFor(vm => vm.Tabs[TabIndex].Groups[GroupIndex].Lines[LineIndex].Items[ItemIndex].ValueString, Model.Tabs[TabIndex].Groups[GroupIndex].Lines[LineIndex].Items[ItemIndex].Name);
                Html.DropDownListFor(vm => vm.Tabs[TabIndex].Groups[GroupIndex].Lines[LineIndex].Items[ItemIndex].ValueString, Model.Tabs[TabIndex].Groups[GroupIndex].Lines[LineIndex].Items[ItemIndex].ValueMultiSelectList);
                break;
            case "radiobutton":
                Html.RadioButtonFor(vm => vm.Tabs[TabIndex].Groups[GroupIndex].Lines[LineIndex].Items[ItemIndex].ValueString, Model.Tabs[TabIndex].Groups[GroupIndex].Lines[LineIndex].Items[ItemIndex].ValueString);
                break;
            case "textarea":
                Html.LabelFor(vm => vm.Tabs[TabIndex].Groups[GroupIndex].Lines[LineIndex].Items[ItemIndex].ValueString, Model.Tabs[TabIndex].Groups[GroupIndex].Lines[LineIndex].Items[ItemIndex].Name);
                Html.TextAreaFor(vm => vm.Tabs[TabIndex].Groups[GroupIndex].Lines[LineIndex].Items[ItemIndex].ValueString);
                break;
            default:
                Html.LabelFor(vm => vm.Tabs[TabIndex].Groups[GroupIndex].Lines[LineIndex].Items[ItemIndex].ValueString, Model.Tabs[TabIndex].Groups[GroupIndex].Lines[LineIndex].Items[ItemIndex].Name);
                Html.TextBoxFor(vm => vm.Tabs[TabIndex].Groups[GroupIndex].Lines[LineIndex].Items[ItemIndex].ValueString);
                break;
        }
                </p>
            </div>
    }   
}
```

If I repeat the code contained in `AddLabelAndEditor` on several parts of the view, it works but it is a lot of code repetition.

Relevant part of my ViewModel:

```
public List<Tab> Tabs { get; set; }

public class Tab
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
public class Group
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Line> Lines { get; set; }
}
public class Line
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string DataType { get; set; }
    public string DataDefaultValue { get; set; }
    public string DisplayTypeEdit { get; set; }

    public string ValueString { get; set; }
    public bool ValueBoolean { get; set; }
    public DateTime ValeDateTime { get; set; }
    public decimal ValueDecimal { get; set; }
    public int ValueInt { get; set; }
    public MultiSelectList ValueMultiSelectList { get; set; }
    public SelectList ValueSelectList { get; set; }
}
```

Any thoughts, ideas, suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: What you are doing is totally wrong. You shouldn't be doing this in your View. That's against the philosophy of MVC. Can you provide more information? What does your Model look like?

Comment: @ataravati I've added the relevant part of my ViewModel. Could you explain further why I shouldn't be doing this and how else I should handle my requirement? Thanks

Comment: First of all, I don't even know why you are doing this. What do you have in your database tables, metadata? What you are doing here only makes sense if you have metadata in your database tables. But, still, even if you have to do this, you shouldn't be doing it in your View. You can create an HtmlHelper, and only pass your Item to it, the rest has to be done in your Controller.

Comment: @ataravati, yes, the database has metadata, which is why I'm doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here is what you can do. In your main View, you will have:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tabs)
```

Then, you need to create the following partial views, and place them under Views/Shared/EditorTemplates:

**Tab.cshtml:**

```
@model YourApp.ViewModels.Tab

<div class="Tab"> @* Or however you want to represent each Tab... *@
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Groups)
</div>
```

**Group.cshtml:**

```
@model YourApp.ViewModels.Group

<div class="Group"> @* Or however you want to represent each Group... *@
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Lines)
</div>
```

**Line.cshtml:**

```
@model YourApp.ViewModels.Line

<div class="Line"> @* Or however you want to represent each Line... *@
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Items)
</div>
```

**Item.cshtml:**

```
@model YourApp.ViewModels.Item

<div class="_20">
  @Html.Label(Model.Name)
  @switch (Model.DisplayTypeEdit.ToLower().Replace(" ", string.Empty))
  {
      case "checkbox":
          @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ValueBoolean)
          break;
      case "dropdownlist":
          @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ValueString, Model.ValueSelectList)
          break;
      case "multiselectlist":
          @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ValueString, Model.ValueMultiSelectList)
          break;
      case "radiobutton":
          @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ValueString, Model.ValueString)
          break;
      case "textarea":
          @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.ValueString)
          break;
      default:
          @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ValueString)
          break;
  }
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create [EditFor Templates](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html) for each of your types:

/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Tab.cshtml :

```
@model Tab

<div>
  // Specific Tab Html
  @Model.Name
  @foreach (var group in Model.Groups)
  {
    Html.Editfor(m => group)
  }
</div>
```

/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Group.cshtml

```
//Group html etc
```

You can chain these and resuse them where ever:

```
@model viewModel

<div>
  @foreach (var tab in Model.Tabs)
  {
    Html.Editfor(m => tab)
  }
</div>
```

It seems what you are doing is what EditFor/Display for templates were specifically designed for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Erik Philips but your answer doesn't quite address my question. How do I 'reuse' the switch statement from AddLabelAndEditor? I want to be able to call it multiple times from one view.

Comment: Put it in the EditorTemplate, then it's reusable.